# How do we create the data frame using column name,number of missing values and their percentage

Tags: r, dplyr

```
Missing_Values = data.frame(colSums(is.na(train)))
Missing_Values_per = data.frame(colMeans(is.na(train))) * 100
data.frame(Column_Name = names(train))
```

i need to create the data frame using these three variables ,could someone help on this

Comment: You could take a look of skimr package, skim function. It gives you the total n and the number of missings by default, you could also create a proportion or percent if you want.     It depends what you want to do with it.  You might want to put together an example showing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
train <- tibble(a = c(NA, 1, 4, NA, NA),
                b = c(6, NA, NA, NA, NA))

train %>% 
  gather(column_name, v) %>% 
  group_by(column_name) %>% 
  summarize(missing_values = sum(is.na(v)),
            missing_values_per = mean(is.na(v)) * 100)
```